# Aligning sections on a page with CSS

Tags: html, css, flexbox, css-selectors

Hi all I'm trying to align my items on my page like the following image:[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BF5Yu.png)

However when I'm finished editing my CSS and HTML my smaller items on the grid don't align with the larger item at the top of the grid, could someone see why editing the CSS code isn't moving my smaller grid of 4 items to align with the larger item?[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ykcv0.jpg)

here is the github to the repository: https://github.com/lingeorge88/Personal-Portfolio-Website

thanks all for the help!

Comment: Hi, welcome to SO. Add your related code here instead of giving a url to a repo. The question will be closed if not added. You can check this out for more details, https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: This question has no code whatsoever, on SO the point is to help users that find your question in the future and links quickly become obsolete, include actual code in your question or it will be closed

Answer (score 0):

Hello @web3newbie you just need to 2-3 correction in your css file.

1. remove `margin-right:auto` from `.smallpics` class.
2. Set `width: 76.8%;` in this class `.hero-item` .
3. remove padding left and right from this class `.Portfolio-grid-item`

Hope it will work for you !!!

Comment: thank you! it worked! how would I shift all of the content more to the left side of the screen?

Comment: @web3newbie please explain in codepen or fiddle what you have done with your code. and what you want to try.